# How to check if one element exist next to another in HTML

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

Say I want to check if a checkbox exist next to a label in HTML using XPATH, how would I go about doing so?

For example:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>This Is A Test</label>
</div>
```

I know I can get the label by using `"//label[.='This Is A Test']"` and I thought I would have been able to see if the checkbox exists using `//label[.='This Is A Test']/parent::div/checkox` but (using Selenium) I get an error that the checkbox does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

> ```
>  [axisname::nodetest[predicate]]
>
>   @* selects all the attributes of the context node
>     .. selects the parent of the context node
> ```

XML Template:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" />

  <label>This Is A Test</label>

  <input type="checkbox1" />
</div>
```

Following XPaths may help You [Check](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi):

```
//label[.='This Is A Test']/../input[@type="checkbox"]
//label[.='This Is A Test']/parent::*/input[@type="checkbox"]
//label[.='This Is A Test']/ancestor::div/input[@type="checkbox"]

False «
//label[.='This Is A Test']/../input[@type="check"] = //input[@type="checkbox"]

True «
//label[.='This Is A Test']/../input[@type="checkbox"] = //input[@type="checkbox"]

//label[.='This Is A Test']/following::input[@type="checkbox1"]  = //input[@type="checkbox1"]

//label[.='This Is A Test']/preceding::input[@type="checkbox"]  = //input[@type="checkbox"]
```

Answer (score 0):

checkbox is not parent of label. As per your x-path, it checks for parent not sibling.

To check label is next to checkbox. you can try the following x-paths.

```
//input[@type='checkbox']/following-sibling:label[.='This Is A Test']
```

or

```
//label[.='This Is A Test']/preceding-sibling:input[@type='checkbox']
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the label name, get the checkbox.

```
//label[text()='This Is A Test']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-**  First you have to get the checkbox label name. So, start your xpath with `<label>` tag using `text()` method, then using `preceding-sibling` keyword get the `<input>` tag along with `type` attribute.

Comment: @MrThursday, Have you try this answer? Does my explanation of `xpath` helped you?

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's resolved your issue. :)